# Getting kicked out of my office, what should I do?

Tags: professionalism, management

I am the CIO at a company in the mid-west (I am the only IT person and I I handle all Strategic, Operational and Tactical operations of Information Systems).

I recently had my yearly performance review with my boss. At that meeting he told me that he is hiring a COO (who will eventually take over as CEO when he retires in 15 months) and wants to give him ***MY*** office and move me into a ***cubicle***. He explained that he could not use the Chairman of the Board's office -- even though the chairman of the board is never here (he uses it about 10 days a year), so I would have to choose from any of the open cubicles. He said he would let me know when to move out when he knows better about when the new COO will start.

First, there is no way I can squeeze everything I have into a cubicle. I have 3 workbenches that I often use simultaneously and a lot more storage than a cubicle. Secondly, well, I have been working at the Executive level (in an office) for the past 25 years of my career. I was given the very beautiful and spacious office when I started at the company as the CIO 10 years ago! And, well, it is the most demeaning and career crushing thing that has EVER happened to me. And I've even had managers tell me to go home and have babies!

I was so shocked that I did not say anything at the time. But now I'm fuming.

How should I approach my boss so that I am able to keep an office?

Comment: Having your own office real estate is that important to you? Is it a perk, a status symbol, some kind of reaffirmation of who you are as a person, what? I am curious to know what your office space means to you because there are times when I have my own office, but I couldn't care less. Did your paycheck take a hit? Did the level of your responsibilities go down? Did your perf review say that you suck?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) and  [this](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) guidance may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan having a nice office is a pretty big perk, most people will work for a bit less in order to be afforded a nice quiet space. Moreover, the OP presents his workplace as a (unhealthy) cube farm with a strong executive-peasant divide. A certain degree of disrespect towards IT may also be under the surface here. The OPs's concerns are in no way petty.

Comment: One thing that has been missed in the comments and answers (understandably, I suppose, as the VERY large majority of questions here are from the 'masses' or at the most, middle management) is that this is a Company Executive. We are not talking about middle, or even upper (regular) management, but one of the primary officers of the company. I cannot even begin to imagine the chagrin and professional embarrassment this will cause (is causing) this CIO then he (or she) shows up on Monday in a regular user's cube.

Comment: I've been a C level for many years at various companies: CIO, CTO and currently CEO.  In my time at the C level I have sat everywhere from a fantastic top floor corner office to a cube down to a windowless closet with barely enough room to put a small desk and chair.  Ultimately the place you sit doesn't define you.  To be honest, a CTO with no employees is a CTO in title only.  You might want to step up your game and play in a bigger pond.

Answer (score 8):

You might turn around "I thought about it, I'll take these three cubicles, remove the walls between them and turn them into a proper office".

There are really two possibilities: Either your boss wants you out, or he is so self centered that he doesn't actually realise what he is doing. In the first case, whatever you do doesn't make a difference. We can assume that he doesn't want you out, because if he does, then no advice will be going to help you. In the second case, he should have no problems accepting your solution to the space problem, which is surely better than his.

I wouldn't put the three cubicles idea as a suggestion, but as a fact of what is going to happen. (Obviously you know your office better than we do and can pick something that is appropriate; whatever will be an acceptable replacement for your office. Since this is both about a nice office and about status, the more costly, the better for your status).

You should absolutely avoid showing any anger at the situation. What your boss has been doing is very wrong, but he hasn't actually figured this out. No need to tell him, just make sure that you get the space you want and need. I would actually *not* say anything about employee perception etc. That would just tell your boss that he made a mistake. Instead you demonstrate that he made the right decision, after some slight modification that you made to his plan (taking three cubicles instead of one).

Comment: I have never seen a new executive postion added to a team where there wasn't a new office built if one didn't exist. If he won't build an office for you, he is telling you that he no longer considers you to be executive level and it is time to look for a new job.

Answer (score 7):

You should have a calm discussion with your boss once you are done fuming, going in mad doesn't help your cause.  Outline why you feel it is inappropriate including employee perceptions and practical matters.  Be ready to suggest multiple alternatives in case the chairman will not give an inch on this.  If there are more than three offices you may suggest who else would be more appropriate to be sent to cube land.

Answer (score -1):

I know walls and elbow room are a big perq,  but could you live with only one or the other? (I seriously considered moving into a closet at one point; management would actually have let me do so... but I was able to find another solution.

Outside of that... look for other ways that the company can make it up to you? See if you can fins some other volunteer to relinquish their office? Try to convince them that it would be good for the incoming exec to spend some time getting to know everyone and that's easier in a cube?

Or get a written promise that you'll get your office back in 15 months, and tolerate it. If there is really a space crunch, snd they are determined to give the new guy an office, *someone* is gong to be unhappy for a while. Find a good reason that it shouldn't be you... Or accept that it is 't about you, just about the shuffle and you happened to draw the short straw this time.

Or, if it really offends you that badly, start looking elsewhere. But these days it's hard for even executives to stay out of the cube farm.

Comment: "Walls" may seem like a perk, but someone at an executive level should have the privacy and security afforded by 4 walls and a door that can be closed. Paperwork in/on their desk, private discussions, lots of phone calls, etc. all demand something more than a basic cubicle, and "move to a conference room when you need to do those things" is not a viable solution.

Comment: An executive -- any manager -- should have walls and privacy _available_. In some companies, that's handled by reserving a meeting room when needed and giving the execs priority access to those, rather than giving them dedicated space. And wile I too am most efficient with a messy desk, thete are companies where even execs are subject to clean-desk polcies andsomehow they make it work -- better filing helps. There are multiple viable solutions to most things; it's a matter of finding the best trade-off... in other words, engineering.

Comment: Privacy should be more than "available". Consider the impression made on a caller when the CIO answers the phone and has to say "I'm sorry, can I call you back in 5 minutes so I can find a private place to talk?" when dealing with a sensitive matter.